# How to convert the below code from C# to VB.net( linq to xml)

Tags: linq-to-xml

I am new VB.net and would like to get some help.
How can I convert the below code from C# to VB.NET

```
    protected override Func<XElement, Person> Selector     
    {         
        get         
        {             
            return x => new Person() 
            {                 
                Id = x.Attribute("Id").GetGuid(),                 
                    FirstName = x.Attribute("FirstName").Value,                 
                    LastName = x.Attribute("LastName").Value,                 
                        Dias = x.Attribute("Dias").GetByte()               

            };         
        }     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this free tool to work convert C# to Vb.net pretty well:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Result:

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property Selector() As Func(Of XElement, Person)
    Get

        Return Function(x) New Person() With { _
            Key .Id = x.Attribute("Id").GetGuid(), _
            Key .FirstName = x.Attribute("FirstName").Value, _
            Key .LastName = x.Attribute("LastName").Value, _
            Key .Dias = x.Attribute("Dias").GetByte() _
        }
    End Get
End Property
```